# Draft.js Editor with initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am working on a React component with an HTML editor.

Currently trying to use a WYSIWYG Editor from Draft.js ([WYIWYG Draft.js](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/))

The docs seem geared towards class-based components, but I am trying to use functional components.

I have HTML text coming from an API call & stored in a variable like so:

```
var values.overview = "<p>this is html text</p>"
```

I want this to be the initial value - visible and editable in the Editor component.

I've gotten as far as getting the text displayed, but I'm quite sure it's a very flawed approach:

`const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML(values.overview))));`

and the component:

```
<Editor
    editorState={editorState}
    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
    editorClassName="editorClassName"                
/>
```

How can I update state based on user input?
Do I need to be using Content State for user input?
What is the best way to manage this state?
I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working....

```
    var overview = "<u>this is my text</u>";

    const contentDataState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(convertFromHTML(overview));
    const editorDataState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentDataState);
    
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(editorDataState);
    
    const onEditorStateChange = (editorStateData) => {
        setEditorState(editorStateData);
    };

    const data = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
    console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
          <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
            editorClassName="editorClassName"
            toolbarClassName="toolbar-class"
            toolbar={{
                options: ['inline', 'list', 'textAlign'],
                inline: {
                    options: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
                },
                list: {
                    options: ['unordered', 'ordered', 'indent', 'outdent'],
                },
                textAlign: {
                    options: ['left', 'center', 'right'],
                },
            }}
        />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: To use draftToHtml() function. first you need to import draftjs-to-html https://www.npmjs.com/package/draftjs-to-html